# Entity Framework creating new entries in database without me telling it to

Tags: c#

I have an application that should work as a bank (school project).

I have five classes

1. List item
2. Customer
3. Account
4. Transaction
5. Logic
6. Repository

In `Customer` I have

```
Public virtual list<Account> Accounts
```

In `Account` I have

```
Public Virtual Customer Customer
```

I have the Customer Customer so that Entity Framework knows who the account belongs to

In `Transactions` I have

```
Public Account Account
```

Now I have a problem when I for instance wants to add an account from my app to a customer, and then add it to the Account table in the database.
If I do so Entity Framework adds a new Customer in the Customer table for some reason. Here's the code:

```
public void DbAddAccount(Account account) 
{ 
    using (var db = new Data.BankContext()) 
    { 
        db.Accounts.Add(account); 
        db.SaveChanges(); 
    } 
}
```

If I add an entry in the Transactions table it will add a new Account AND a new Customer in the table.

The following is created in the database based on my code

```
 "dbo.Accounts",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Balance = c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 18, scale: 2),
                    Interestrate = c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 18, scale: 2),
                    AccountType = c.String(),
                    AccountNumber = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    LoanInterestRate = c.Decimal(precision: 18, scale: 2),
                    CreditLine = c.Decimal(precision: 18, scale: 2),
                    MaxFreeWhitdraws = c.Boolean(),
                    Discriminator = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    Customer_Id = c.Int(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Customers", t => t.Customer_Id)
            .Index(t => t.Customer_Id);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Customers",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    FirstName = c.String(),
                    LastName = c.String(),
                    SSN = c.String(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Transactions",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Date = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    TransactionType = c.String(),
                    Amount = c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 18, scale: 2),
                    Balance = c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 18, scale: 2),
                    Account_Id = c.Int(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Accounts", t => t.Account_Id)
            .Index(t => t.Account_Id);
```

Where do I get it wrong?

Comment: It'd probably be a good idea to show the code that you're using to update the customer.

Comment: This is the code i use in the Repository to add an account to the database  public void DbAddAccount(Account account)
        {
            using (var db = new Data.BankContext())
            {                
                db.Accounts.Add(account);                
                db.SaveChanges();                
            }
        }

Comment: Does the account get seeded with a customer before being passed in?  Please try to add a complete example.

Comment: I have some accounts that get seeded but this is when i try to create a new account. Everything works fine in the application and the customers List<Account> gets uppdataed correclty. Its just when i try to add the newly created account to the database aswell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of your Foreign Key constraints.

Your `Transactions` table has a **non-nullable** column (`Account_Id`) which is a foreign key to the `Accounts` table. This means that there **must** be a value for `Account_Id` and that value **must** correspond to an `Id` value in the `Accounts` table. When you add an entry to the `Transactions` table with no `Account_Id` specified, EF "helpfully" creates a new `Accounts` entry with default values and uses its `Id` as the `Account_Id` value.

Since `Accounts` also has a foreign-key relationship with `Customers`, the same process applies for this (and any other) newly-added account as well.

Comment: Ok I think I understand what you are saying. But from what I am told since i created the public Account Account in transactions should it not use the information that is currently in Account-table? Since im telling the Transaction that its a specific account already in the database that is requesting the transaction?

Comment: If your Transaction object has the Account set to a valid Account object (at time of saving), then yes. I didn't get that from your question but if that is the case something else is going on.

Comment: When i create a new transaction I set the Account property to the Account that is calling the method. Im sending the Account to the method. So i can use it when i create the transaction object.

Comment: public void DbDeposit(Account account, decimal amount)
        {
            using (var db = new Data.BankContext())
            {
                Transactions newTrans = new Transactions();
                newTrans.Account = account;
                newTrans.Date = DateTime.Now;
                newTrans.Amount = amount;
                newTrans.TransactionType = "Deposit";
                newTrans.Balance = account.Balance + amount;

                db.Transactions.Add(newTrans);

Comment: And the `account` provided to `DbDeposit` was already saved in the database before calling the method? Specifically, this specific object instance was retrieved from (or added to, during this execution) the DbContext?

Comment: Yes the account provided to DbDeposit is already in the database. the Account was added before to the database and not in the dbcontext created by DbDepoist